# Using a singular or agreement with "audience"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

it's

> 1. our audience are children and adults
> 2. our audience is children and adults
> 3. our audiences are children and adults

I am kind of confused

Comment: I have improved your question title and formatted your question.